# How to consistently get the python_type from SQLAlchemy for nonstandard types?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, crud, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a function to write a Python dict as a row to a Postgres table, via the SQLAlchemy expression language. I want to check that the values passed in that dictionary match the corresponding column types of the database table.

So far I have something like

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

def create(table, new_row):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(~my db address~) 
    config_metadata = MetaData()
    config_metadata.reflect(engine)
    target_table = config_metadata.tables[table]
    target_column_types = {col.name:col.type.python_type for col in target_table.c}
    # ... Code to check that target_column_types match types of new_row
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html) `python_type` gives the corresponding types expected to be returned, like `int` for Integer and `dict` for JSONB. However, if I call it on an INT4RANGE Postgres column, I get a `NotImplementedError()`. Empirically, I can use SQLAlchemy to query this same range column and get a result back, which is of type `psycopg2._range.NumericRange`

Why doesn't `.python_type` called on that column simply give me `psycopg2._range.NumericRange`, then? And, is there anything I can do to retrieve a given expected-return-type in cases when `python_type` is not implemented?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating a custom `IntRangeType` and have my models use that for the column definition instead.

```
import intervals
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import INT4RANGE
from sqlalchemy_utils import IntRangeType as _IntRangeType

class IntRangeType(_IntRangeType):
    class INT4RANGE(INT4RANGE):
        python_type = type(intervals.IntInterval)

impl = INT4RANGE
comparator_factory = _IntRangeType.comparator_factory
cache_ok = True

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(IntRangeType, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.interval_class = intervals.IntInterval
```